# Writing a subquery for a relation's relation in Objection.js

Tags: objection.js

I'm using version 2.2.15 at the moment and I'm following the [relation subqueries](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/relation-subqueries.html)
 recipe. I've outlined my models and their relationships towards the bottom.

Currently, I'm fetching an event as well as it's post count using this query:

```
const events = await Event.query().select([
  'events.*',
  Event.relatedQuery('posts')
    .count()
    .as('numberOfPosts'),
  ]);
```

Which works fine - but how can I include the count of each of the event's post's users, that is, the total amount of user's going to an event. I've tried using a refs so far without luck.

Models and their relationships:

Event:

```
posts: {
  relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
  modelClass: Post,
  join: {
    from: 'events.id',
    to: 'posts.eventId',
  },
},
```

Post:

```
event: {
  relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
  modelClass: Event,
  join: {
    from: 'posts.eventId',
    to: 'events.id',
  },
},
users: {
  relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
  modelClass: User,
  join: {
    from: 'posts.id',
    through: {
      // users_posts is the join table.
      from: 'users_posts.postId',
      to: 'users_posts.userId',
    },
    to: 'users.id',
  },
},
```

User:

```
posts: {
  relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
  modelClass: Post,
  join: {
    from: 'users.id',
    through: {
      // users_posts is the join table.
      from: 'users_posts.userId',
      to: 'users_posts.postId',
    },
    to: 'posts.id',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like so, i haven't tried it in code so you might need to tweek a few things, what i'd do usually if i have a count that needs to be tracked is keep a field on the `posts` that increments users in the application logic and value is retrieved much faster, in your case you can just count the `users_posts` where the `postId` match and get your `users` count and save it in that field

```
const events = await Event.query().select([
   'events.*',
   Event.relatedQuery('posts')
   .count()
   .as('numberOfPosts'),

   Event.relatedQuery('posts')
   .join('users_posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'users_posts.postId')
   .join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users_posts.userId')
   .countDistinct('users.id')
   .as('numberOfPostUsers'),
]);
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll be marking this as the accepted answer. With this query, if a user belongs to multiple posts it increases the number of users, how can I get the unique count? e.g Post 1 has users A + B. Post 2 has users A + C. The total count is 4 instead of whereas I'd like to to be 3 (A + B + C). Cheers

Comment: try using `.countDistinct('users.id')` instead of `count()` if it works for you i'll update the answer